# DateTime format in Bamboo Build number

Tags: bamboo

I am trying to configure Bamboo builds. Bamboo provides  ${bamboo.buildNumber} as a special variable. However this variable is just simple auto increment integer. When I am using this in build, I have to use it as 1.0.${bamboo.buildNumber}. It would generate builds with numbers 1.0.1, 1.0.2 etc.

However, I would like to generate build with format 1.0.0.$(Date:yyMMdd)$(Date:HHmm) similar to TFS build definitions. It should generate builds with numbers like 1.0.0.170210.0510 or 2.10.0.160210.0510.

I can very well write batch file or Powershell to do this, however, if there is already an option available, I would like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

use bamboo.buildTimeStamp variable